# Return inherited DTO from API controller along with parent fields to the client

Tags: json, api, asp.net-core, serialization, dto

I have a parent DTO as following:

```
public abstract class BaseDTO
{
   public list<string> message = new list<string>();
}
```

and a child class:

```
public class MyDTO : BaseDTO
{
   public string name { get; set; }
}
```

now when I try to view MyDTO in swagger schema section, the message field of BaseDTO does not appear in the list of fields also when I try to

```
return ok(MyDTO)
```

in my web api controller this field is not shown on client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` Nuget Package, and add the following code in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Below is my test code, it works fine:

Model:

```
public class BaseDTO
{
    public List<string> message = new List<string>() { "test1","test2","test3" };
}

public class MyDTO : BaseDTO
{
    public string name { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test() 

    MyDTO myDTO = new MyDTO();
    myDTO.name = "name";

    return Ok(myDTO);
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

[image]

If you don't want to set value in `BaseDTO`, you can also set `myDTO.message`:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test() 
{
    MyDTO myDTO = new MyDTO();
    myDTO.message.Add("test1");
    myDTO.message.Add("test2");
    myDTO.name = "name";

    return Ok(myDTO);
}
```